# Update in a Formula Field

Tags: apex, formula-field, field-update, lookup-field

I have Cus_Object__c and Account__c. In my Cus_Object__c I'm insert values by apex.
And, I have formula field called Cus_Status__c in Account.
**Formula Value is :** `Cus_Object__r.Status__c;`

```
Cus_Object__c cObj = [Select Name,Status from Cus_Object__c where id=:accId];
cObj.Status = 'Success';
```

When the Cus_Object__c object status field updated as 'Success'. My Cus_Status__c formula field should be update as 'Success'.

Is possible?
Any Suggestions??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas are calculated/derived in real-time, and no data is stored for these values. As such, you can't "update" a formula directly. You need to update the values from which the formula is derived in order to "update" the formula.